# How are basement levels in shopping malls designated?

Tags: word-usage, abbreviations, speech

In a mall or somewhere with multiple basement levels, what is the proper way to designate each underground level?

We have: *first floor*, *second floor*, etc. for above ground floors.

Underground levels are usually referred to as *B1*, *B2*, etc.

If we are going to ***say*** something:

> *The food court is on ____.*

What would be the full way to say *B1*?

1. *The first basement floor*
2. *The first basement level*
3. Or something else entirely?

Comment: I have always just used 'Basement 1' and 'Basement 2'   (First Basement, Second Basement reminds me too much of hobbits.)

Comment: You also confusingly see "lower ground floor". I don't think anyone knows what it means! :)

Comment: I have encountered lifts/elevators where the buttons for selecting the underground levels are marked with negative numbers (-1, -2 etc.).

Comment: @Erik That would be the standard in most of Europe. I don't recall ever seeing B1, etc., in Continental Europe, though I have seen it in Britain. On the other hand, I don't recall seeing -1 in the US, so perhaps Britain is just in between on this.

Comment: Joe Blow: "Lower ground floor" seems quite clear to me. It's the floor below the ground floor.

Comment: @ColinFine it sounds like a low part of the ground floor to me. Or some other nonsense. Like if the ground floor was split into a lower and upper portion.

Answer (score 5):

There are, unfortunately, no North American standards for floor numbering in commercial buildings. P1 / P2 are common if it's a parking level and are spoken just like that (they can also be 8 floors above ground). "Basement" in a shopping mall will probably be avoided, as it implies that's where the cheap goods, rejects, maintenance facilities and extra stock are put. I have seen "Lower" used in place of Basement once or twice: "Did you look on L2?"

Comment: Good point on the connotation of basement, however, if it were a discount or outlet type of facility, perhaps they would play up that angle with [*bargain-basement*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bargain-basement) "2: markedly inexpensive".

Answer (score 2):

This is a reasonable question without a similarly reasonable answer, because, at least in the US, these are influenced by regional custom and sometimes company practices. I've seen the designations of levels change when a shopping center was sold by one company to another. That said, most commonly, if the level containing the food court is "B1", the full way to say it is

> The food court is on level B1.